# How to declare a method that cannot change the class members in Java?

Tags: java, oop

In C++ we do a constant method, and so it can't change the value of the class members, but how can I do it in Java?
I tried the final method declaration, which would be the equivalent to the consts in C++, but final methods are another different thing.
I want to make a getter method, so it cannot change the values, only read it. Like a read-only method.

Comment: *which would be the equivalent to the consts in C++* ... err no. Don't **assume** what keywords in other languages mean. Read the language spec or a good book that TELLS you what keywords mean. Anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: I think the question is undertandable and good. The False Friend problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) is always a trap we easily fall into. Maybe a canonical Q&A about the difference between immutability in C++ and Java would be usefeful, if it already does not exist(?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, it's *not possible* to declaratively prevent a method from changing non-final fields. There's no such thing as "const correctness" in Java.

If a class field is non-`final`, then it can be changed by any method of the class.

Note that `final` works differently on fields and variables versus methods and classes:

- A `final` field or variable is a constant. Its value cannot be changed once assigned.
- A `final` method cannot be overridden by child classes. `final` on methods has nothing to do with "constness".
- A `final` class cannot be extended. `final` on classes has nothing to do with "constness".

---

Your options in Java are:

1. Make your class immutable (i.e. mark all its fields `final`).
2. Just write your getters (and other non-mutator methods) carefully :)

---

One more note. Even on fields and variables, Java's `final` differs from C++'s `const`. For example:

- `final` variables can't be changed once assigned, *but* you can assign them *after* the declaration. Example:

  ```
    final int value;
    if (condition) {
        value = 1; // Ok!
    } else {
        value = 2; // Ok!
    }
    value = 3; // Compile error: value already assigned.
  ```
- `final` class fields must be assigned - either directly or from within a constructor. But these fields may be assigned *anywhere* within a constructor. There's no special thing like C++'s "initializer list" in Java.
- The field/variable/parameter declaration `final Object obj` in Java is roughly equivalent to a *(const-)reference to a non-const object* in C++. This means, you *can't re-assign the reference*, but you *can* change the referenced object itself. An example:

  ```
    // Note that (obsolete) Date class is mutable in Java.
    final Date myDate = new Date();

    myDate = new Date(); // Compilation error: can't reassign a final reference!

    myDate.setTime(4711); // Ok, mutating referenced object is allowed!
  ```

Comment: Please, would you put a reference?

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA It is almost like requiring "Put a reference that God does *not* exist." :) It is not easy to put a reference that something is *not* possible.

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA here's a short and simple tutorial on `final` in Java: https://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword

Comment: @HonzaZidek, you've convinced me :) Added that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Final method means it can't be overriden.